# Advanced String replacement in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am trying to replace strings in a file, i.e. version numbers 4.0.0 to 5.0.0. However, on using the replace method, versions such as 24.0.0 are also getting changed, which is not desirable.

For example:  I want 4.0.0 to get changed to 5.0.0 throughout the file. But, 24.0.0 should remain as it is.

I wrote the code for simple string replacement [fo is my file here]:

```
fo = open ('ex.txt', 'r')
for line in fo:
    print(line.replace('4.0.0', '5.0.0'))
```

Sample input:

```
This is a file
It contains a version number
That version number is 24.0.0
Ideally, it should remain 4.0.0
But 4.0.0 should get changed
```

The desired output is

```
This is a file
It contains a version number
That version number is 24.0.0
Ideally, it should remain 5.0.0
But 5.0.0 should get changed
```

The second re solution given is working fine for 24.0.0. But 4.0.0.15 is getting changed to 5.0.0.15, thats not desirable

print(re.sub(r'\b4.0.0[^.]', '5.0.0 ', line)) worked, but it is replacing 4,0.0 with 5.0.0. Thats also not desirable.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have written. That way the community can help you better.

Comment: could you provide the code and a a part from the string?

Comment: use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Answer (score 0):

try using regex:

```
import re

test = "This is a file It contains a version number That version number is 24.0.0 Ideally, it should remain 4.0.0 But 4.0.0 should get changed"

print(re.sub(r'\b4.0.0', '5.0.0',test))
```

output:

```
This is a file It contains a version number That version number is 24.0.0 Ideally, it should remain 5.0.0 But 5.0.0 should get changed
```

for not matching 4.0.0.15, use this:

```
print(re.sub(r'\b4.0.0[^.]', '5.0.0 ', test))
```

The explanation:

we used [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module which is the python module that provides regular expression matching.

`re.sub(pattern, repl, string)`: Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.

the `pattern` we used is `\b4.0.0[^.]`.

this part `\b4.0.0` matches any 4.0.0 that became after empty string. but that matches 4.0.0.15 too. so to stop that from happening we used `[^.]` which matches any character except `.`, hence, It's not matching `4.0.0.15` anymore.

Comment: It's not working. 24.0.0 is remaining as it is, but 4.0.0 is not getting changed to 5.0.0

Comment: then try this: 
    print(line.replace(r'\b4.0.0', '5.0.0'))

Comment: if that didn't work then you should provide at least a part from the text

Comment: @RashmiSingh check my new Edit please.

Comment: @RashmiSingh check it out now

Comment: it worked! Could you please explain the solution once?

Comment: @RashmiSingh I explained it a bit. check my Edit. also if your problem is solved now, mark the answer as accepted to make us now that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, regexes are a powerful tool and I recommend to not use them for everyday string replacement.

If you know for a fact that before `4.0.0` there is a space you can just use

```
line.replace(' 4.0.0 ' , ' 5.0.0 ')
```

(The space after is for eliminating the replacement of `4.0.0.5`)

If you don't know for a fact that there is a space before the `4.0.0` then the regex pattern needs to be more complex than Mohamed's answer.